# Lesti FPC, Redis and Magento multistore. How to Clear cache for only one store?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache, redis

I have successfully set up Lesti FPC with latest Redis, including session and backend cache, on a Magento 1.9.2 with a few stores. Everything is working really great.

My question is, if possible, how I can clear the cache for a certain store? I have access to redis-cli via ssh, if needed.

The problem is, if I flush the cache in Magento, the cache is cleared for all stores.

Comment: I don't think you can do this for each store unless you specify tags for each store and then setup a separate redis instance for each store

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brent! That sounds way too difficult for me, and way over my skill level. I'll think I leave this for now, and continue to use my cache warmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not clear cache per store unless you specified tags for each store. Even then you would have to modify Lesti to be able to clear cache on each store view. (You would also have to do this with the regular Magento cache as well)